# Spring cloud and Consul: HttpClientErrorException: 404 NOT_FOUND

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-cloud, consul

I'm working on 2 applications based on Spring cloud consul.
The first one Called Hello1 and expose a simple hello world Web service. the second one Called Hello2, try to call the web service exposed by the first application. The 2 applications use consul as service discovery.

For Hello2, I have the following code:

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class HelloWorldConsController {

@Autowired
private DiscoveryClient discoveryClient;

@Autowired
protected RestTemplate restTemplate;


protected String serviceUrl;

@RequestMapping("/hello2")
public String hello() {
    log.info("Hello calls ");

    return restTemplate.getForObject("http://hello1-Example/hello1",   String.class);
 }
}
```

config file (yml):

```
 spring:
  application:
   name: hello2-Example
 profiles:
 active: native

  cloud:
   consul:
    config:
     enabled: true
   host: localhost
   port: 8500
```

For Hello1 application:

```
 @Controller
 @RestController
 public class HelloWorldController {

  @RequestMapping("/hello1")
  public String hello() {
    return "Hello1";
  }
```

}

config file (yml):

```
 spring:
  application:
   name: hello1-Example
 profiles:
 active: native

  cloud:
   consul:
    config:
     enabled: true
   host: localhost
   port: 8500
```

Here is my dependencies:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>Angel.SR3</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <lombok.version>1.16.2</lombok.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

However, when I call hello 2 application http://localhost:1234/hello2, it gives me the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 NOT_FOUND
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:614)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:570)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:237)
```

Comment: What do your dependencies look like?

Comment: I updated my post with dependencies

Comment: spring-cloud-consul does not work with `Angel.SR3` nor spring boot 1.2.x. Use the latest: Brixton.M3.

Comment: I have the same exception with the last version.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem. Do you have project you can share?

Comment: Thanks a lot Spencer it's work. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's work with the following pom:

```
<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>Brixton.M3</version>
</parent>

<properties>
<lombok.version>1.16.2</lombok.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.M3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.M3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>

</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-all</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.M4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>${lombok.version}</version>
</dependency>
```